# Edit/create user with read/write access MongoDB

Tags: swisscomdev

After deploying my Flask app, I get the following error when trying to access the MongoDB service:

> `OperationFailure: not authorized on [db_name] to execute command ...`

I understand this is because the db user does not have read/write access to the database. But I'm not able to create a new user or change permissions. `db.grantRolesToUser()` returns "not a function" and `addUser()` gives me no permission... What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things:

- Bind the app to the service using `cf bind-service` (or the web portal)
- In the app, parse the `VCAP_SERVICES` environment variable to get the credentials

This will ensure you app gets readWrite permissions on your database.

Here's a few helpful links in this regard:

- https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/devguide/services/application-binding.html
- https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html#VCAP-SERVICES
- https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/service-offerings/mongodb.html

Comment: Hm but this is what's already been done.. I bound it through the web portal, and I use the credentials from VCAP_SERVICES - it's with these credentials that I get the "not authorized" error. Any clue why?

Comment: @abilic Well, your error says you're not authorized to execute a command...what command were you trying to execute? You're probably simply not allowed to use that command.